# More than one JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I currently have two frames, when you run the application the first JFrame that shows is a login, it has two input fields and a button. When the user logs in and is verified, I would like to close the frame and start up the second one.

So, the only thing I can think of doing is doing `setVisible(false)` for the login frame and `setVisible(true)` for the `Main` frame.

Is there a better way to do this, or is that the only way?

Comment: If you do this, you'll also want to call `dispose()` or set the `JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personnally, I would start up your second `JFrame` immediately and replace your first frame with a modal `JDialog` which would be owned by the `JFrame`.

See also this answer to [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/928711)

Here is a basic demo of what I suggest:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestLogin {
    private JFrame frame;
    private boolean authenticated;
    private JTextField login;
    private JPasswordField password;

    protected void initUI() {
        frame = new JFrame(TestLogin.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected void showLoginDialog() {
        authenticated = false;
        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "Please provide your credentials");
        dialog.setModal(true);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        login = new JTextField(40);
        password = new JPasswordField(20);
        JLabel loginLabel = new JLabel("Login:");
        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
        JButton ok = new JButton("OK");
        ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Here perform authentication and set authentication flag to appropriate value
                authenticated = true;
                if (authenticated) {
                    setUpFrame();
                    dialog.dispose();
                }
            }
        });
        JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                if (!authenticated) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });
        dialog.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(ok);
        buttonPanel.add(ok);
        buttonPanel.add(cancel);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        panel.add(loginLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        panel.add(login, gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        panel.add(passwordLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        panel.add(password, gbc);
        panel.add(buttonPanel, gbc);
        dialog.add(panel);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
        while (!authenticated) {
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    protected void setUpFrame() {
        frame.add(new JLabel("Successfully authenticated"));
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TestLogin testLogin = new TestLogin();
                testLogin.initUI();
                testLogin.showLoginDialog();
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson Getting there ... Thanks :-)

Comment: This seems to work! So now my main JFrame starts, and it starts up a JDialog, is there any way to hide the Main JFrame from view? I tried `setVisible(false);` but that doesn't hide it.

Comment: Never mind, just needed to add `this.setModal(true);` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that.
E.g. you could reuse your 1st `JFrame`. Therefore remove the components you got on your 1st frame, add the ones for the 2nd and then `repaint()` the frame.
But I wouldn't consider that as good practice.
As Andrew Thompson suggested, you could also use a `CardLayout` to just initialize one `JFrame`, show your login-card and then switch to the fully initialized 2nd full-application card. This way you will get rid of those repaints.
You could also show your 2nd frame (your application first) and then use a modal `JDialog` to the let user log in.

Comment: *"But I wouldn't consider that as good practice."*   Instead, see `CardLayout`.

Comment: You're right. I totally forgot about this. This way there wouldn't any repaints needed. (Well, I totally hate them though ;) )